# Editor for post Source code as it for blog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, ckeditor, editor

I am creating a blog site in MVC and I want to use a text editor to write content, insert image and past source code like C# code, html code, sql code etc.

I have tried TinyMCE http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php  and Ckeditor http://ckeditor.com/demo .

There are lots of feature in both editor but they both are unable to show source code as it in preview like C# code variable color etc.

Please suggest me any editor which is useful to post Source code as well.

Thanks

Comment: Search for 'js library syntax highlighting'.

Comment: @allcaps: ... and then how you'll use it in an editor? Still, the question asks to recommend a tool, so it needs to be closed.

Comment: I didn't down vote. You just markup the code snippets as `<code>...</code>` in your WYSIWYG-editor and let the js lib do the syntax highlighting in the rendered page.

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear to me what exactly you are looking for, so it would be cool if you could edit your question and make it more precise.

Two things that come to my mind - note that they only pertain to CKEditor, I don't know TinyMCE at all.

If you want to be able to **see the source code of the content that you are writing** in your editor (so the entire blog post, headers, paragraphs, text styles etc.), use the Source Code Editing feature ([demo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sourcearea.html), [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_sourcearea)). Just click the "Source" toolbar button and you will see the HTML source code of whatever content you created in your WYSIWYG editor.

If you want to be able to **insert pretty code snippets** into your blog post (read: fragments of code with syntax highlighting), use the optional Code Snippets feature ([demo](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/codesnippet.html), [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_codesnippet)). Just note that this is an optional plugin, so you will need to [add it to your custom build](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_widget_installation) first.

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) supports a customizable syntax highlighting for (nearly) all languages and has also the feature to copy a selection of syntax highlighted code as HTML or RTF formatted text to clipboard.

By using **Copy as HTML Document** in submenu **Copy Special** of menu **Edit** it is even possible to copy to clipboard even the code for an entire HTML document for the selected syntax highlighted block.

An UltraEdit script could be coded to convert the HTML or RTF formatted block in clipboard to other formats like BBCode or MarkDown or Wiki syntax if other formats are required. Such a script would be quite easy as just a set of regular expression replaces must be applied to content in clipboard to make such a conversion.